# Castling during the endgame

Tags: endgame, castling, famous-moves, famous-games

Are there any famous games where castling occurred during the endgame?

Comment: I vaguely remember a game, where after Anand castled, the opponent resigned.

Answer (score 9):

The game [Lasker - Thomas](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1259009), Lasker could have ended with a castling checkmate, but instead he played “18.Kd2#.” Some versions of that game I've seen may have ended with “18.O-O-O#.”

```
[Title "Edward Lasker-George Alan Thomas, London, Casual Game, 10/29/19"]
[FEN ""]

1. d4 e6 2. Nf3 f5 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. Bg5 Be7 5. Bxf6 Bxf6 6. e4 fxe4 7. Nxe4 b6 8. Ne5 O-O 9. Bd3 Bb7 10. Qh5 Qe7 11. Qxh7+ Kxh7 12. Nxf6+ Kh6 13. Neg4+ Kg5 14. h4+ Kf4 15. g3+ Kf3 16. Be2+ Kg2 17. Rh2+ Kg1 18. Kd2#
```

Was this an endgame? White did not have his queen on the board, and it was definitely the end of that game.

Comment: I love that game but it's definitely not an endgame in my opinion. It's a miniature, a sacrificial attack, a king hunt...

Comment: Yes, this is an amazing game, that I'd not seen before, and whether or not it addresses the literal question, I'm very glad to have seen it! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is [a famous game](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1266220) between two famous players that ends with “30...0-0.”

```
[Title "Timman-Kasparov, Eurotel Trophy, 1998"]
[FEN ""]

1.d4 d5 2.c4 c6 3.Nf3 Nf6 4.Nc3 dxc4 5.e3 b5 6.a4 b4 7.Nb1 Ba6 8.Qc2 b3 9.Qd1 e6 10.Be2 c5 11.O-O Nc6 12.Ne5 Rc8 13.Na3 cxd4 14.Naxc4 Qd5 15.Bf3 Ne4 16.Nxc6 Rxc6 17.Nd2 f5 18.Re1 d3 19.Nxb3 e5 20.Bd2 Rb6 21.Bxe4 fxe4 22.Nc1 Rxb2 23.Bc3 d2 24.Rf1 Bxf1 25.Bxb2 Bc4 26.Ne2 Bb3 27.Nc3 Bxd1 28.Nxd5 Bb3 29.Nc3 Bb4 30.Nd1 O-O
```

The world record of late castling is move 48, achieved in two games, according to the [fascinating page](http://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/records) by Tim Krabbe.

Game 1: Kingside Castling

```
[Title "Neshewat-Garrison, Detroit, 1994"]
[FEN ""]

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 c5 3. Nf3 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Qa5+ 5. Bd2 Qb6 6. Nb3 Ne4 7. e3 Qf6 8. Qf3 Qxf3 9. gxf3 Nxd2 10. N1xd2 Nc6 11. a3 d6 12. Be2 g6 13. Rb1 a5 14. O-O a4 15. Nc1 Bf5 16. e4 Be6 17. Rd1 Bh6 18. Kg2 Nd4 19. Bd3 Ra5 20. Nf1 Rg5+ 21. Ng3 Nxf3 22. b4 Bg7 23. Be2 Nh4+ 24. Kh1 Bh3 25. f4 Bg2+ 26. Kg1 Bxe4 27. Nd3 Bd4+ 28. Kf1 Rxg3 29. hxg3 Nf5 30. Rdc1 Nxg3+ 31. Ke1 Be3 32. Rd1 Nf5 33. Rb2 Bd4 34. Ra2 Ne3 35. Rc1 Ng2+ 36. Kf1 Be3 37. Rc3 Bd4 38. Rc1 Be3 39. Rb1 Nxf4 40. Rd1  Ne6 41. Nf2 Bf5 42. Bd3 Nd4 43. Bxf5 Nxf5 44. Ke2 Bh6 45. Ne4 Bg7 46. c5 dxc5 47. Nxc5 Nd4+ 48. Kf2 O-O 49. Nxa4 e5 50. Nc5 Nb5 51. Rd7 b6 52. Rb7 Nc3 53. Rc2 e4 54. Rxb6 e3+ 55. Ke1 Rd8 56. Rc1 h5
```

Game 2: Queenside Castling

```
[Title "Somogyi-Black E., New York, 2002 "]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 g6 2. d4 Bg7 3. Nc3 b6 4. Nf3 Bb7 5. Bf4 Nf6 6. Bc4 Nc6 7. O-O Nxe4 8. Nxe4 d5 9. Bd3 dxe4 10. Bxe4 e6 11. c3 Qe7 12. Ne5 Bxe5 13. dxe5 Na5 14. Bd3 a6 15. Qg4 h5 16. Qg3 h4 17. Qe3 Qd7 18. f3 Nc6 19. Rad1 Ne7 20. Bg5 h3 21. g4 Nd5 22. Qf2 c5 23. a3 Qc7 24. c4 Ne7 25. Qg3 Nc6 26. Bf6 Rh7 27. Rf2 Nd4 28. Bf1 b5 29. b4 bxc4 30. Bxc4 Qc6 31. Rd3 a5 32. b5 Qd7 33. a4 Bd5 34. Rc3 Bxc4 35. Rxc4 Qd5 36. Rc1 Nb3 37. Re1 c4 38. f4 Nc5 39. Qa3 Qd4 40. Qf3 Qd5 41. Qxd5 exd5 42. Rd1 Ne4 43. Rc2 Nxf6 44. exf6 Rh4 45. g5 Rg4+ 46. Kh1 Rxf4 47. Re2+ Re4 48. Rde1 O-O-O 49. Rxe4 dxe4 50. Kg1 Kb7 51. Rc1 Rd2 52. Rxc4 e3 53. Rc1 Rg2+ 54. Kh1 Rg4 55. Re1 Rxa4
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a [game](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1306169) where castling takes place on the **40th move** in a postion that is truly that of an endgame. Tim Krabbe lists as the [103rd most fantastic move](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess/mfm101110.htm) in chess history.

```
[Title "Viktors Pupols-Jerald Meyers, Lone Pine California USA, 3/13/1976"]
[FEN ""]
[startply "78"]

1.d4 Nf6 2.Nf3 c5 3.d5 g6 4.c4 b5 5.cxb5 a6 6.bxa6 Bxa6 7.Nc3 Bg7 8.Bg5 h6 9.Bd2 O-O 10.h3 e6 11.dxe6 fxe6 12.Qc2 g5 13.g4 Nc6 14.Nd1 Nd4 15.Nxd4 cxd4 16.h4 d3 17.exd3 Rc8 18.Qa4 Bb7 19.Rh3 Bc6 20.Qa5 Qxa5 21.Bxa5 Nxg4 22.hxg5 hxg5 23.Rg3 Nh2 24.Be2 Bf3 25.Bc3 g4 26.Bxg7 Kxg7 27.Ne3 Kf7 28.Nxg4 Bxg4 29.Bxg4 Rc2 30.Bd1 Rxb2 31.Rh3 Rg8 32.Rg3 Rh8 33.Be2 e5 34.a4 d5 35.a5 e4 36.dxe4 dxe4 37.a6 Nf3+ 38.Bxf3 exf3 39.Rxf3+ Ke7 40.O-O-O Ra2 41.Re1+ Kd7 42.a7 Ra8 43.Rf7+ Kd6 44.Ree7 Rc8+ 45.Kd1 Rc5 46.Rd7+ Ke6 47.Rh7 Rca5 48.Ke1 R5a4 49.Kf1 Ra1+ 50. Kg2 R4a3 51.Rhe7+ Kf6 52.Rb7 R3a2 53.Rh7 Ke6 54.Rb6+ Kd5 55.Rh5+ Kc4 56.Rb7 Rxa7 57.Rxa7 Rxa7 58.Re5 Kd4 59.f4 Rg7+ 60.Kf3 Rg1 61.Re8 Kd5 62.f5 Kd6 63.Kf4 Kd7 64.Re2 Rg8 65.Ra2 Ke7 66.Ke5 Rb8 67.Rh2 Rb5+ 68.Kf4 Kf7 69.Kg5 Rb6 70.Rh7+ Kf8 71.Ra7 Rc6 72.Ra8+ Kf7 73.Rb8 Ra6 74.Rb1 Rc6 75.Rb7+ Kf8 76.f6 Rc1
```